# Problem with printing own Linked List and implementing 2 methods

Tags: java, generics, linked-list, nodes, functional-interface

I created my own Linked List using nodes, and I have few methods to do.

Methods in main:

```
//List<Person> females = peopleFromWarsaw.getWithFilter(p -> p.getName().endsWith("a"));
// Dont know how to implements this methods.

//        ObjectContainer.removeIf(p -> p.getAge() > 50);
//        peopleFromWarsaw.storeToFile("youngPeopleFromWarsaw.txt",
//                p -> p.getAge() < 30, p -> p.getName() + ";" + p.getAge() + ";" + p.getCity());
```

At the begging i made a linked list and tried to print elements from list but doesnt work.
At first it looks like it doesn't have a method toString but class Person has toString. I guess the program takes the node but I want to print object.
Maybe u can see what is the problem with code, basically nodes and methods in Object Container are fine.

Secondly i have a problem with implementing methods in main (getWithFilter,removeIf and storeToFile)
No matter how I write method in ObjectContainer, always intelij tells me that cannot use lambda and underline p.getName (p -> p.getName().endsWith("a"));
In class Person i have getters and setters with fields name,age.

Maybe someone could explain how properly write this methods ?

```
public class ObjectContainer<T> {

    private Node head;
    private Node tail;
    private final Predicate<T> predicate;

    public ObjectContainer(Predicate<T> predicate) {
        this.predicate = predicate;
    }

    static class Node {

        private Object object;
        private Node next;

        Node(Object object) {
            this.object = object;
        }
    }

    public void add(T object) {
        if (!predicate.test(object)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Element can not be added");
        }
        Node newNode = new Node(object);
        if (head == null) {
            head = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
        } else {
            tail.next = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
        }
    }

    public int size() {
        int count = 0;
        Node current = head;

        while (current != null) {
            count++;
            current = current.next;
        }
        return count;
    }

    public void push(T new_data) {
        Node new_node = new Node(new_data);
        new_node.next = head;
        head = new_node;
    }

    public void insertAfter(Node prev_node, T new_data) {
        if (prev_node == null) {
            System.out.println("The given previous node cannot be null");
            return;
        }
        Node new_node = new Node(new_data);
        new_node.next = prev_node.next;
        prev_node.next = new_node;
    }

    public void append(T new_data) {
        Node new_node = new Node(new_data);
        if (head == null) {
            head = new Node(new_data);
            return;
        }
        new_node.next = null;

        Node last = head;
        while (last.next != null)
            last = last.next;

        last.next = new_node;
        return;
    }

    public void printList() {
        Node tnode = head;
        while (tnode != null) {
            tnode = tnode.next;
            System.out.println(tnode);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you don't want to print the node, but the object contained within. Also, you want to print the first object, too. That is

```
public void printList() {
    Node tnode = head;
    while (tnode != null) {
        System.out.println(tnode.object);
        tnode = tnode.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right, i want to print the object, but program takes the node.

Comment: Your code prints the node by `System.out.println(tnode)`, I changed it to `System.out.pritnln(tnode.object)` to print the object of tnode.

Comment: And maybe you know, how could I implements methods removeIf and getWithFilter from main

Comment: The signature of those methods depend on whether you want to use the predicate that was given to the constructor. If not, e. g. the signature of method removeIf looks like `void removeIf(Predicate<T> predicate)`. You pass the predicate in the same way you pass it to the constructor.

Comment: okay, so method should be like
public void removeIf(Predicate<T> predicate){
"deleting nodes" ???

Comment: Yes. Have you tried it?

Comment: if (predicate.test((T) key)) {
            Node temp = head, prev = null;
            if (temp != null && temp.object == key) {
                head = temp.next;
                return;
            }
            while (temp != null && temp.object != key) {
                prev = temp;
                temp = temp.next;
            }
            if (temp == null)
                return;

            prev.next = temp.next;
        }
    }
Made something like this and still doesnt work, can i text priv to you ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248576/discussion-between-mihe-and-patryk-szymanczyk).